# Meaning of CRM column in buffer list from `C-x C-b`?

Tags: buffers, documentation, symbols, buffer-list

In the Buffer List, I wonder what the CRM column means and `.`,  `*`,  `%` and `D` mean in the column? For example

```
CRM Buffer                Size  Mode              File
. * .emacs                3294  Emacs-Lisp        ~/.emacs
 %  *Help*                 101  Help
    search.c             86055  C                 ~/cvs/emacs/src/search.c
 %  src                  20959  Dired by name     ~/cvs/emacs/src/
  * *mail*                  42  Mail
D%  HELLO                 1607  Fundamental       ~/cvs/emacs/etc/HELLO
 %  NEWS                481184  Outline           ~/cvs/emacs/etc/NEWS
    *scratch*              191  Lisp Interaction
  * *Messages*            1554  Messages
```

Answer (score 13):

```
`C' shows `>' if you have marked the buffer to be displayed,
          `D' if you have marked it for deletion, and
          `.' for the buffer from which you came (current).
`R' shows `%' if the buffer is read-only.
`M' shows `*' if the buffer is modified, and
          `S' if you have marked it for saving.
```

Comment: thanks. (1) what do "marked to display, marked for deletion, marked for saving" mean? Does "a buffer marked for deletion" mean to delete the file connected with the buffer or to close the buffer only? (2) How should I apply the action on a marked buffer?

Comment: Use `C-h m` in the buffer-list buffer to see the answers to such questions. Use that key sequence in any buffer to get information about that buffer's mode. In this case, you use `m`, `s`, and `d` to mark for display, saving, and deleting, respectively, and `x` to eXecute `S` and `D` markings. No, deleting a file's buffer does not delete the file.